# String Output Alignment in Java

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop, indexing

[practice question part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jq7Cl.png)

[practice question part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNXgG.png)

This is a practice question which is rather hard for me. Below is my code for the static method(the main method is fixed -unchangeable, and signature of static method is given), and my intention is to get the matches between the characters and print them out.

But there are some concerns:

1) How do i ensure it doesn't print when all the strings are aligned but there are extra characters which makes the boolean false and the result to be not aligned instead? (e.g amgk as second string & first string is Java Programming Course)

2) How do i make it print right? currently the spaces are off and the letters aren't what is wanted.

3) If there is more than one character a in str1, which do i choose to put, and how do i omit the rest when there is already a match?

Would really appreciate a pseudocode to help guide a beginner like me in solving this problem.

```
public class Q3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the first string:");
    String input1 = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the second string:");
    String input2 = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println();

    if (matchStrings(input1, input2)) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("There is an alignment as shown above.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No alignment can be found.");
    }
}
    public static boolean matchStrings(String str1, String str2) {
    // Modify the code below to return the correct value.
    boolean isMatch = false;
    //int firstChar = str2.charAt(0);
    //int lastChar = str2.charAt(str2.length()-1);
    int prevIndex = 0;

    System.out.println(str1);

    for (int j = 0; j< str2.length(); j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i<str1.length();i++) {
            char charToSearch = str1.charAt(i);
            int newIndex = i;

            if (str2.charAt(j)== charToSearch) {
                for (int k = prevIndex; k < newIndex-1; k++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.print(charToSearch);
                //prevIndex=newIndex+1;


                isMatch = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return isMatch;
}
}
```

Comment: Start with more easier tasks instead

Comment: If you want help, you should create show us what you expect and what you actually get, in the question, not in links. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think you didn't understand the instructions. To "align", String 1 has to contain all the letters in string 2, and in the same order. That is, if the first letter is found, then the second letter should be somewhere after it, the third letter somewhere after that, etc. - So there is no "match" when string 2 contains a letter that is not in string1.

Answer (score 0):

I think two of the first few structures you learn in a Data Structures course is the stack and queue. Thus, I will provide an implementation using a Stack. You can use a Stack to store the test String and `pop` each char element off the stack when it is matched up with a character in the first string. Otherwise you would output an empty space `" "` in the `matched` String object:

```
    Stack s2 = new Stack();
    String str1 = "Java Programming";
    String str2 = "amg";

    for(int i = str2.length()-1; i >= 0; i--){ //Need to populate the stack backwards...LIFO
        s2.push(str2.charAt(i));
    }

    String match = ""; //Used to store the matching line

    for(int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++){
        if(str1.charAt(i) == (char)s2.peek()){
            match += s2.pop().toString();
        }
        else
        {
            match += " ";
        }
    }

    System.out.println(str1);
    System.out.println(match);
```

You can also use a Queue for this, but I will leave that for you to learn on your own. Also practice on creating your own Stack object using arrays and integer pointers to handle overflow/underflow.

The above code would print out:

[image: Tested Char Comparison]

Comment: thanks for the answer! I am taking an intro course where we don't learn push and pop yet. i'm still wondering how to do this with simple for loops, and other java api methods